# Circular dependency struct, error redefinition of struct when using forward declaration

Tags: c++, c, struct

The following code compiles in C, using ARMCC under Keil, However fails to compile in C++, using G++ under eclipse. The original code had some const keywords but that seems to be causing another, less important issue, so I removed them for now.

```
struct MENU
{
    struct MENU *   NextMenu;
    struct MENU *   PrevMenu;
    void            (* InitFunction)(void);
};

typedef struct MENU MENU_T;

MENU_T MENU_A; // <- this forward declaration is needed for circular reference between structs
MENU_T MENU_B;
MENU_T MENU_C;

MENU_T
MENU_A = // <- However redefinition error occurs here
{
    .NextMenu = &MENU_B,
    .PrevMenu = &MENU_C,
    .InitFunction = 0,
};

MENU_T
MENU_B =
{
    .NextMenu = &MENU_C,
    .PrevMenu = &MENU_A,
    .InitFunction = 0,
};

MENU_T
MENU_C =
{
    .NextMenu = &MENU_A,
    .PrevMenu = &MENU_B,
    .InitFunction = 0,
};
```

As far as I can tell, the first line is a declaration and not a definition, so the "error redefinition" should not occur...

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages, for example, you don't need `typedef struct` in C++.

Comment: Please do not use all-caps for anything other than macro names and enum constants.  It's confusing and hard to read.

Answer (score 4):

With `MENU_T MENU_A;`, you do not "forward declare" a variable named `MENU_A`, you rather define it. Hence, when you later write `MENU_T MENU_A = { ... }`, you get an error indicating that you redefine a variable with the same name `MENU_A`.

For just declaring a variable (without defining it), use keyword `extern`:

```
extern MENU_T MENU_A; // declaration of MENU_A, not a definition
extern MENU_T MENU_B;
extern MENU_T MENU_C;

MENU_T MENU_A = 
{
    .NextMenu = &MENU_B,
    .PrevMenu = &MENU_C,
    .InitFunction = 0,
};

...
```